# CodeHS Billboard Class AP CS A

Tags: java, object, arraylist, methods

I am struggling with the CodeHS Java problem Billboard Top 10. I am trying to reference a Musician object within the top10 ArrayList, but I keep getting the error:

> non-static variable top10 cannot be referenced from a static context.

Here is the code I have for this segment:

```
public void add(Musician m) {
    //if less than 10 musicians on the list and musician has platinum status, add musician to top10 array list
    if(m.getIsPlatinum(m.getAlbumsSold())&&top10.size()<10) {
        top10.add(m);
    }
    //if already 10 musicians (and platinum), call replace method
    else if(m.getIsPlatinum(m.getAlbumsSold())&&top10.size()==10) {
        replace(m);
    }
    // else print musician couldn't be added to top10 list
    else System.out.println("The musician could not be added to the top10 list.");
}

public static void replace(Musician replacer) {
    //if lowest # weeks on top40 is lower than # weeks of new musician: replace old
    Musician temp = top10.get(0);
    int lowest40Weeks = temp.getWeeksInTop40();
    int lowestIndex = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i<top10.size(); i++) {
        temp = top10.get(i);
        if(temp.getWeeksInTop40()<lowest40Weeks) {
            lowest40Weeks = temp.getWeeksInTop40();
            lowestIndex = i;
        }
    }
    if(lowest40weeks<replacer.getWeeksInTop40()) {
        top10.set(lowestIndex, replacer);
        System.out.println(replacer.getName() + " has replaced " + top10.get(lowestIndex).getName() + " on the top 10 list.");
    }
    //print message to user about replacement
    //else print musician can't be added because not enough weeks on top40
    else {
        System.out.println(replacer.getName() + " could not be added to the top 10 list because they do not have enough weeks in the top 40.");
    }
}
```

All of my issues are in the replace method when I reference **top10** in a method. 
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Musician is an object, not a class. Static belongs to a class. Remove static from your replace() so it reads `public void replace(Musician replacer)`

Comment: There is no telling if you call that method from a static context however, given the code you've provided

Answer (score 0):

Why is Replace static in the first place?
You can't reference a variable that isn't static in a function that is. So just make the replace function not static.